# Signal control on multiple processes

Tags: vhdl

This might be and easy question, but does one knows how to control a single STD_LOGIC signal in multiple processes? I've been doing this way:

... signal declaration:

```
-- update control state machine
signal update               : STD_LOGIC := '1'; -- address or data changed, rewrite update incoming
signal a                    : STD_LOGIC := '0'; -- control for update, addr and data change
signal b                    : STD_LOGIC := '0'; -- control for update, process
```

... state machine control

```
-- signal cannot be updated inside multiple processess
process(a,b)
begin
    update <= not update;
end process;
```

... signal usage

```
-- state machine to control update required
process(rst,...)
begin
    if update = '0' then
        a <= not a; -- update <= '1';
    end if;
end process;
```

I believe this is not the best way to create a synthesizable code.

Is this solution typically applied?

Thank you!

Comment: Im not entirely sure what your problem is. If you assign a signal in multiple processes, you will get multiple drivers on the signal. But it is fine to read a signal in as many processes as you want. In your code you have an error in the first process, because update is not in the sensitivity list. A and B should not be in it.

Comment: To clarify:
* The signal cannot have multiple drivers, like you said.
* The signal can be read in multiple processes, no problem.
* The is no problem with the code posted, it executes just fine.
* The issue would be that the code is too complex as a solution for a simple problem, and it requires non-clock and non-reset signal to be in the sensitivity list - it seems to be the worst solution possible.

Comment: From what you have said, then I suggest you dont really understand how VHDL works or how it maps to hardware. Do you have a circuit diagram for your intended circuit? Can you post the real code, not this simple example that has no problem. I highly doubt your problem is too complex to describe in VHDL.

Comment: Your posted VHDL code is not enough to answer your question on how to create a  signalling and interaction scheme for multiple processes and/or state machines. If you have working solution, you might want to post that solution on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get hints for improving the code and/or handshake mechanisms.